# Обращение к полям родительского класса при динамическом наследовании

Tags: python

мне необходимо создавать объекты, наследованные от объектов, определяемых в рантайме. При этом надо обращаться как к методам, так и полям родителей. Я пытаюсь сделать это следующим способом:

```
class base:
    def __init__(self, ham = 'ham'):
        self.ham = ham    
    def spam(self):
        print('spam!')

def wrap_with_A(cls, a = 5):
    class A(cls):
        def __init__(self, a):
            self.a = a            
        def spam(self):
            for k in range(self.a):
                super().spam()

    return A(a)

w_obj = wrap_with_A(base, 3)

w_obj.spam() # все хорошо
w_obj.ham    # AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'ham'
```

При этом методы вызываются, а при попытке доступа к полям вылетает AttributeError. Хотелось бы знать почему и как этого избежать?
Заранее спасибо

---

Разобрался. забыл инициализировать родителя:

```
def wrap_with_A(cls, a = 5):
class A(cls):
    def __init__(self, a):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = a            
    def spam(self):
        for k in range(self.a):
            super().spam()

return A(a)
```

Ругался корректно. Поля ham действительно не существовало

Answer (score 1):

забыл инициализировать родителя:

```
def wrap_with_A(cls, a = 5):
class A(cls):
    def __init__(self, a):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = a            
    def spam(self):
        for k in range(self.a):
            super().spam()

return A(a)
```

Comment: Вы не могли бы переместить это дополнение в вопрос?

Comment: переместил. а этот ответ надо удалить?

Comment: @strawdog но ведь это же ответ, а не дополнение

Comment: @RamadanovVasiliy Если вы этим ответили на свой вопрос, то все в порядке.Пусть так и остается